# Should I capitalize "the" if it has a comma preceding it in a title?

Tags: writing, style-manuals

If I am citing a resource and "the" comes before the main title, should I put the "the" at the end with a comma preceding it?

Comment: Do you mean, for example, "A quotation from Bible, The"?

Comment: I would say: if you are citing a resource, do not place *The* at the end, keep it at the front.  Only when this reference is placed inside an alphabetized list would you move *The* to the end. And in that case, keep it capitalized.

Comment: As GEdgar indicates, listing a title as, for example, _Wind in the Willows, The_ is standard in indexing work, which uses alphabetical order as the organizing principle. But for a footnote, a source note, a bibliography, or main text, it would be quite unusual to put _The_ after _Wind in the Willows_, separated by a comma, instead of in front of it as it appears on the title page of the book. That, at any rate is the preference of _The Chicago Manual of Style_, _Words into Type_, and other style guides that I'm aware of.

Answer (score 1):

"the" comes before the "main title" doesn't really make sense, unless it is part of the title.  In which case, "the" should be capitalized and hold its position.

HOWEVER,

There has been an issue in bibliographies (and libraries, and business listings in the phone book, and... iTunes playlists..., etc., ad nauseam.) where searching for a title is made difficult because intuitively, no one wants to search the endless "The" section for a work that can be found easier by the second word in the title.

It might very well be the case the specific style manual you are using will tell you to cycle "The" to the back of the title, preceded by a comma.  In that case, yes, indeed, "the" is capitalized and your citation would be:

*Hardy Boys, The.*

BUT

The Hardy Boys are just some characters, albeit awesome characters, that are created and no one is potentially offended by altering the title.  Certain texts, namely religious texts, should not be altered as one would The Hardy Boys.  This might be addressed in your respective style manual; regardless, if it says the same rule applies, I would exercise caution, evaluate your audience, and decide whether or not to proceed in following the rule.  If it is against your own belief, you don't follow the rule - no one can challenge you on that.

*The Holy Bible*

*The Holy Qur'an*

*The Communist Manifesto*

Essentially, any text that has held import enough globally that has caused people to spend their lives and other's lives over, then out of respect, you don't break the title.

But, I consider breaking the title in general to be an outmoded rule to follow.  In particular, with the onset of the Information Age, the integration of more and more complex search algorithms, the tendency of authors to avoid a title starting with "The" for a published work that would apply to the problem of alphabetical ordering, I can still understand why a style manual would recommend following the rule.  However, I just disregard - I've never been called out on it so long as it is consistent.

One way to reconcile this would be alphabetizing as if "The" weren't there, but still keeping the Title Intact.  Even indexes have found ways to maintain the title - yet still making the title easy to find alphabetically.

- - 

Short Answer - Yes; Title, The.  Except texts that demand a special respect.

Long Answer - Probably not; see all that stuff above.

Comment: No references given.  So treat this merely as the strange opinions of J Mac Jordan.

Comment: I hardly believe The Hardy Boys as high quality literature is at all a strange opinion relegated to myself; I believe it is actually widely known, established, and agreed upon fact.

Comment: So it should always be "The Lord of the Rings" and never "Lord of the  Rings, The" or even "Lord of the Rings", despite that fact that probably 90% of the time it is written as the last? My worldview is blown.